When does $n! = a 2^a$?
Question
Today as I was answering another question on this site, I realized that $4! = 3\cdot 2^3$. I thought this was interesting so I decided to see if I could prove that $n=4$ and $a=3$ is the only solution to $n! = a \cdot 2^a$ for $a,n \in \mathbb{N}$. While trying this I also found the now trivial solution $n=2$, $a=1$. But I think I also found a proof for why these are the only two solutions. I am hoping to get verification that this proof is correct, and perhaps a more elegant proof. I am also interested in a similar question of when $n! = a\cdot b^a$ for $a,b,n \in \mathbb{N}$ and $a,b\neq 1$, but that might have to be a new question when I look into it more.
Proof for odd $n$
I will first deal with the case where $n$ is odd. We will define $n! = r q$ where $q=2^a$. We can also write $n! = n!! (n-1)!!$. Here, $n!!$ will not have any factors of $2$ so we can say that $r \ge n!!$. We also have that $(n-1)!!$ will contain all the factors of 2 that $n!$ has, hence we can say that $(n-1)!! \ge q$. Then using the fact that if $2^a > a$ we have $(n-1)!! > a$. To wrap this up we will note that $n!! \ge (n-1)!!$ so we can combine all these inequalities to get:
$$ r \ge n!! \ge (n-1)!! > a $$
Hence $r$ cannot be equal to $a$. It now remains to show that $n! = a\cdot 2^a$ cannot be true when $n >5$ is even.
Proof for even $n$
I will prove this by induction with the base case being $n=6$. For $n=6$ we if we try to write $n! = r2^a$ then we have that $r\ge 45$ but there are only 4 factors of $2$ so $a\le4$. Hence we can see that $6!$ cannot be written as $a\cdot 2^a$ for $a\in \mathbb{N}$. I will now induct over the even numbers.
Inductive step
Assume $n-2 > 5$ is even and $(n-2)! = r'\cdot 2^{a'}$ with $r' > a'$ and $r'$ is odd. The assumption that $r'$ is odd gives us that the maximum value of $a'$ is still less than the minimum value of $r'$ for all possible values of $r'$ and $a'$. We want to show that if $n! = r\cdot 2^a$ then $r>a$ for all possible values of $r$ and $a$.
Starting with our inductive hypothesis, $(n-2)! = r'\cdot 2^{a'}$, we will multiply both sides by $n(n-1)$. The LHS gives us $n!$ and the RHS gives us $n(n-1)r'2^{a'}$. Because $n-1$ is odd, it must fully contribute to $r$, that is $r \ge (n-1)r'$. Then, using that $n-1 > 6$ we have $r > 6r'>6a'$. I will now show that $a \le 2a'$ by looking at the factors of 2 of $n!$. If this is the case then we have $r > 6a' \le 3a$ so $r > a$.
Let $2^{m-1}< n \le 2^m$ for $m\ge 3$, then $n$ can add at most $m$ factors of 2 to the RHS, $a \le m+a'$. However, $(n-2)!$ must contain a factor of $2^{m-1}$ and $2^1$ so we have that $a' \ge m$. Combining these to eliminate the $m$ we get $a \le 2a'$. As I mentioned above this directly gives that $r > a$ and hence there can be no values of $n>5$ such that $n! = a\cdot 2^a$.
Q.E.D.

For those interested, here is a link to the more general question: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4972802/when-does-n-a-cdot-ba

I didn't go through your proof. Although I did work out a different proof.

Fact $1$: For $n\geq 6$, $n!> (n-1)\cdot 2^{n-1}$

Consider $n\geq 6$. By induction, $n!>(n-1)\cdot 2^{n-1}$. Indeed the base case with $n=6$ is true and supposing $k!>(k-1)\cdot 2^{k-1}$ for $k\geq 6$ gives that $(k+1)! \geq \color{blue}{(k+1)(k-1)} \cdot 2^{k-1} \geq \color{blue}{2k}\cdot 2^{k-1} = k\cdot 2^k$ proving the claim.

Fact $2$: $v_2(n!) \le n-1$.

Recall Legendre's formula to give the highest power of a prime $p$ dividing $n!$, viz. $v_p(n!)$. Using this formula we get
$$v_2(n!) = \sum_{r=1}^{\left\lfloor\log_2(n)\right\rfloor} \left\lfloor \frac{n}{2^r} \right\rfloor \le \sum_{r=1}^{\left\lfloor\log_2(n)\right\rfloor} \frac{n}{2^r} = \frac{n/2(1/2^{\left\lfloor \log_2(n) \right\rfloor} - 1)}{1/2 - 1} \le \frac{n/2(1/2^{\log_2(n)} - 1)}{1/2-1} = n-1$$

Thus $n-1 \geq v_2(n!) = v_2(a2^a) \geq a$. Thus $n-1 \geq a$ and so $(n-1)2^{n-1} \geq a2^a$. Thus for $n\geq 6$, $n! > (n-1)\cdot 2^{n-1} \geq a\cdot 2^a$. Thus $n! > a\cdot 2^a$ for such $n$; contradiction. Thus it suffices to check $n\in [0,5]$ and we find the following solutions: $(n,a) \in \{(2,1), (4,3)\}$.

Cool! I’ve never seen that formula before I’ll have to look into it. Thank you!

@Nic It is a very commonly used formula. You can read more on wiki: here.

@Nic if you feel like this answer resolves your question you may mark it as accepted. Just a friendly reminder.

Thanks for your help, this formula helped me prove the more general question: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4972802/when-does-n-a-cdot-ba/4972803#4972803
