When does $n! = a \cdot b^a$
This is a more general question of a similar question I asked a few weeks ago: When does $n! = a\cdot 2^a$. In that question, I proved (and Sahaj proved much more elegantly) that $n! = a \cdot 2^a$ only has integer solutions at $(2,1)$ and $(4,3)$.
I then started looking into the question of whether there were non-trivial integer solutions to $n! = a\cdot b^a$ (i.e. $a,b \neq 1$). My thinking went as follows: try to follow the same ideas as my previous proof where I set it up as $n! = r \cdot b^a$ and show that the maximum value of $a$ is strictly less than $r$ and hence this won't have any integer solutions. I also started trying to disprove it because if I got stuck I thought this would help me to find a counter example that might shed more insight onto the question.
While trying this, I found a solution that I will post as an answer to this question; however, I would still greatly appreciate any other proofs.

As stated in the question I will try to prove $n! = r \cdot b^a$ implies that $r>a$ and hence equality cannot occur (except for the cases we already know. To start out I will list a fact that I am not able to prove myself but I have verified from this site.
Fact:
For every natural number $m > 1$, there exists a prime number $p$ such that $m < p < 2m$.
Lemma:
We can assume that $b$ is prime because the maximum value for $a$ in the equation $n! = r \cdot b^a$ occurs when $b$ is prime. It is worth noting that the maximum value of $a$ may also be achieved when $b$ is composite, but it cannot exceed that of prime $b$.
Proof:
To start, we will directly apply the fact. Let $n = 2m (+1)$, here I have added the case for odd $n$ in parenthesis. Applying the fact we get the existence of a prime number $p$ such that $m(+1)<p<2m(+2)$. From here, we can see that there must be at least one factor of $p$ in $n!$. However, multiplying everything by 2 gives us $2p > 2m(+2) \ge n$ so there cannot be another factor of $p$ in $n!$. Simply, $n!$ only has one factor of $p$. Because there is only one factor of $p$, and we assumed that $a\neq 1$ (otherise the answer would trivially be $b = n!$), we have that $r \ge p$.
Next, we can apply the lemma and use Legendre's Formula for the highest power of a prime $b$ dividing $n!$:
$$v_b(n!) = \sum_{k=1}^{\left\lfloor\log_b(n)\right\rfloor} \left\lfloor \frac{n}{b^k} \right\rfloor \le \sum_{k=1}^{\infty} \frac{n}{b^r} $$
We can see that this is now a infinite geometric sum and we have $v_b(n!) \le \frac{n}{b-1}$. Noting, that the value of $v_b(n!)$ is the highest power of $a$ we can have for a given prime $b$ we now have the equation $a(b-1) \le n$.
In the first paragraph we have that $r \ge p > n/2$ and in the second paragraph we have that $n \le a(b-1)$. Combining these, we get:
$$ r > a(b-1)/2 $$
We note that this if $b > 2$ then this result directly gives $r>a$. Hence for $b > 2$ and $a \neq 1$ there cannot be any integer solutions to the equation $n! = a \cdot b^a$. Because we already covered the case where $b=2$ we have found all possible integer solutions to this equation.
